# Replaced /system/bin/toolbox. How to I revert that?

Tags: applications, root-access, file-system, permissions, file-management

I renamed the original /system/bin/toolbox" to "toolbox_alt".
I replaced the file /system/bin/toolbox with a file that was supposed to work, but doesn't work at all.
My filemanagers and the most terminal comands have stopped working and I apparently lost root access.
I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (N9005) (International) running the newest Cyanogenmod nightly.
Can anyone help me deleting the current toolbox and renaming the "toolbox_alt" back to "toolbox" ?

Thanks ahead

Comment: Have you tried re-rooting?  You might be looking at a factory reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it myself.

1. I went to the recovery menu (CWM)
2. Mounted /system
3. Plugged it into my Laptop
4. Opened ADB on my Laptop Comand: adb shell
5. went to /system/bin and replaced the file

Hopefully this helps other who do the same mistake!